# Swift: Custom Searchbar layout issue

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have tried updating my search bar using this [link](https://freakycoder.com/ios-notes-30-how-to-customize-uisearchbar-6f026531914b) but I am having weird layout issue around the corner. My current situation is this:
[image]

I want to remove the dark grey corners.
The code that I am using is this:

```html
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
            if let textfield = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
                
                if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
                    
                    // Rounded corner
                    backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
                    backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
                    
                    // Background color
                    backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0.12)

                    //glass icon colour
                    if let glassIconView = textfield.leftView as? UIImageView{
                        glassIconView.image = glassIconView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                        glassIconView.tintColor = UIColor.white
                    }
                    
                    // Clear Button Customization
                    if let clearButton = textfield.value(forKey: "clearButton") as? UIButton {
                        clearButton.setImage(clearButton.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
                        clearButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
                    }
                }
            }
            
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        } else {
            
            tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        }
```

Please point out towards the error in my approach. Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lb06d4q38wxiss/SearchControllerSampleProject.zip?dl=0) for the bare minimum project.

Comment: What do you absolutely want ?.

Comment: Can you see the corners in the search bar? I want it to be plain, remove the curved edges.

Comment: so the main problem, just to get correct corner, right ?.

Comment: Yes, updated in the question as well.

Comment: try backgroundview.layer.clipsToBounds = true;

Comment: Value of type 'CALayer' has no member 'clipsToBounds'

Comment: ah.. I catch your error.. that's problem is background color with alpha, try set alpha to 1.0

Comment: if my suggest is correct, can you make tick on my answer below ?. :D

Comment: When I change the alpha to 1.0, it becomes white completely. Even if I change the background colour to 248 from 255. Corners become perfect but the rest is just white inside.

Comment: UIColor.lightGray @Farrukh

Comment: This colour that I want to use isn't exactly lightGray though it doesn't work with the lightGray as well. :D

Comment: you get this problem If you still want alpha

Comment: Alpha value is actually dictating the background colour here. Also the coreners issue. I have tried settng the exact colour but somehow only get white background.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

The issue is with the cornerRadius of 2.
The Searchbar applies a cornerRadius of 10 and as such you see the underlying background of the bar.

Set your backgroundView cornerRadius to 10 and you're good

```
backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

Comment: Tried but same issue.

Comment: Still the same, the problem with the corners is still there.

Comment: @FarrukhJaveid I've edited my answer to apply the changes to the textfield directly

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: @FarrukhJaveid can you make a sample proejct? or share the code where you add the searchController please

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Awesome man but the problem is, I have to set the corner radius to 2. :(

Comment: @FarrukhJaveid won't work for backgroundView. May be if you apply it to the searchbar itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem is backgroundview.backgroundColor. try set alpha to 1.0, incorrect if you set alpha < 1.0

```
backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0.12)
```

you can use light gray instead, its seem you want light gray.

```
backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
```

Comment: Tried but it didn't work. It changed the colour but the issue with the corners is still there.

Comment: I tested it already, cuz of your alpha.. if you set alpha to 1.0.  it's will ok.. can you add one more propertied. backgroundView.layer.maskToBounds = true